# Javascript 3 Dimensional Array Assignment Bug

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a 3 dimensional javascript array of size [5][5][4], the [4] is a boolean array. I have initialized all values to false. The issue I'm having is that when I try to switch a single value (e.g. [0][0][1]) to true, it sets EVERY value ending with the same [1] dimension equal to true ([0][1][1], [1][0][1], etc.) I haven't been able figure out why or how this is happening, so any help is appreciated. My code for setting up the array, and assigning the value is below.

```js
this.maxX = 5;
this.maxY = 5;

var grid = [];
var falseBoolArr = [false, false, false, false];

for (var i = 0; i < this.maxX; i++) {
  grid[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < this.maxY; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = falseBoolArr;
  }
}
grid[0][0][0] = true
grid[0][0][1] = false
console.log(`Grid at 0,0,0 = ${grid[0][0][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 0,1,0 = ${grid[0][1][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 1,0,0 = ${grid[1][0][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 0,0,1 = ${grid[0][0][1]}`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting everything to the same array. There will all be *references* to the same `falseBoolArr` array:

```
grid[i][j] = falseBoolArr;
```

So when you change that, the change is reflected everywhere. You need to make a new array with each loop. Something like:

```
for (var j = 0; j < this.maxY; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = [false, false, false, false];
}
```

If you need to set `falseBoolArr` once for some reason. You can make an explicit copy in the loop using `slice()`:

```js
this.maxX = 5;
this.maxY = 5;

var grid = [];
var falseBoolArr = [false, false, false, false];

for (var i = 0; i < this.maxX; i++) {
  grid[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < this.maxY; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = falseBoolArr.slice();  // makes a copy
  }
}
grid[0][0][0] = true
grid[0][0][1] = false
console.log(`Grid at 0,0,0 = ${grid[0][0][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 0,1,0 = ${grid[0][1][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 1,0,0 = ${grid[1][0][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 0,0,1 = ${grid[0][0][1]}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting each item in the 2nd array to a variable reference, not an array.  So, when you change any of them you change them all as they all reference the same variable.

Initialise without using a variable and the problem disappears...

```js
this.maxX = 5;
this.maxY = 5;

var grid = [];

for (var i = 0; i < this.maxX; i++) {
  grid[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < this.maxY; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = [false, false, false, false];
  }
}
grid[0][0][0] = true
grid[0][0][1] = false
console.log(`Grid at 0,0,0 = ${grid[0][0][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 0,1,0 = ${grid[0][1][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 1,0,0 = ${grid[1][0][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 0,0,1 = ${grid[0][0][1]}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't intialize with variable the problem is due to variable initialization, 
Remove `falseBoolArr` variable and directly use it in for loop.

```
this.maxX = 5;
this.maxY = 5;

var grid = [];

for (var i = 0; i < this.maxX; i++) {
  grid[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < this.maxY; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = [false, false, false, false];
  }
}
grid[0][0][0] = true
grid[0][0][1] = false
console.log(`Grid at 0,0,0 = ${grid[0][0][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 0,1,0 = ${grid[0][1][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 1,0,0 = ${grid[1][0][0]}`);
console.log(`Grid at 0,0,1 = ${grid[0][0][1]}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript Arrays and Objects are passed by reference, which means that `grid[0][1][0]` and `grid[0][0][0]` are pointing to the same object. That's the cause for that behavior.

Try replacing   `grid[i][j] = falseBoolArr;` with `grid[i][j] = falseBoolArr.slice(0);`